# Can we install Ruby on Rails on Mac but not virtual machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

lots of instructions online show that we need to install Ruby on Rails on linux. Can we actually install it on Mac? Because Ubuntu is too slow on Mac so far, I wanna change to Mac itself instead of using a virtual machine.

Comment: Of course. The http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html docs would seem like a better place to get started, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, we can use MacOS for development, and Linux for production.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. It's simple. Open Terminal and follow this steps:

**Install Homebrew:**

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

**Upgrade ruby version:**

```
$ brew install rbenv ruby-build

$ echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile

$ rbenv install 2.5.0
$ rbenv global 2.5.0
```

**Install last rails version:**

```
$ gem install rails -v 5.1.4
$ rbenv rehash
```